# migrating cocos2dx to v2.1.5

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, objective-c++

First of all, I know this is such an outdated version. But I really need an answer. I'm very new to iOS and cocos2dx, I just got some old code and I'm trying to update cocos2dx to v2.1.5.

My problem is `CCMutableArray` has been deprecated, replaced with `CCArray`. I know that in the latest version `CCArray` has also been deprecated.

But my question is how do I properly update this part of the code without getting unexpected results...

```
static CCMutableArray<CCString*>* getCsvList(string path);
CCMutableArray<GiftInfo*>* giftList;
```

I believe I can't just do a drop-in replace like:

```
static CCArray<CCString*>* csvList(string path);
CCArray<GiftInfo*>* giftList;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use CCArray like this

```
static CCArray* csvList( string path );
CCArray* giftList;
CCArray* stringList;
//
//
//you can add object of CCObject class or derived from CCObject class to CCArray
//example
GiftInfo* gift = GiftInfo::create();
giftList->addObject(gift); //GiftInfo must derived from CCObject class

CCString* myString = CCString::create("new string");
stringList.addObject(myString);

//when getting value from CCArray, it will return object of CCObject, you have to cast it to your class
CCString* getValue = (CCString*)stringList.objectAtIndex( index );
GiftInfo* getGift = (GiftInfo*)giftList.objectAtIndex( index );
```

for more information see CCArray class inside cocos2d-x code.

Note: It is better to updatre to version 2.2.6 instead of 2.1.5, Its is latest version of cocos2d-x 2.x series.

Comment: Oh, I thought 2.1.5 was the latest for 2.x, thanks for that information. I'll try this out tonight. Will give feedback soon.

Comment: sorry its version 2.2.6, you can download from here http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cocos2d-x-v2-2-6-released/18903